# Deserializing using Jackson based on JSON type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `JSON` payload I am attempting to deserialize using `Jackson` that looks like:

```
{
  "id": "12",
  "type": "foo",
  "created": "2011-03-20T31:12:00+00:00",
  "data": {
    "object": {
        objectId: 1
        fizz: "bizz"
    }
}
```

There are 3 different "type" responses possible `{foo, bar, foobar}` and, depending on which type is in the payload, the `"object"` node will have different data underneath it (type foo has fizz for example). I am attempting to write some deserializers that will detect the type, and output a `class` containing the contents of `"object"`. I can basically ignore the `id` and created fields. The types of classes are as follows:

```
public interface ObjectType {
   String getId()
}

public class Foo implements ObjectType {
   String objectId;
   String fizz;

   String getId() {
      return objectId;
   }
}

public class Bar implements ObjectType {
   String objectId;
   String test;

   String getId() {
      return objectId;
   }
}

public class FooBar implements ObjectType {
   String objectId;
   String something;

   String getId() {
      return objectId;
   }
}
```

What is the simplest way to do so in Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to write a custom deserializer. A stub implementation could be as follows:

```
class ContainerDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Container> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8976140492203602443L;

    public ContainerDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ContainerDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Container deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
        String type = node.get("type").asText();
        ObjectType obj;
        String objId = node.get("obj").get("objectId").asText();
        switch (type) {
        case "foo":
            String fizz = node.get("obj").get("fizz").asText();
            obj = new Foo(objId, fizz);
            break;
        case "bar":
            String test = node.get("obj").get("test").asText();
            obj = new Bar(objId, test);
            break;
        default:
            // Error handling
            obj = null;

        }

        return new Container(id, type, obj);
    }
}
```

For the implementation I assumed you have the following Container class:

```
class Container {
    private String type;
    private int id;
    private ObjectType obj;

    public Container(int id, String type, ObjectType obj) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ObjectType getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(ObjectType obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I also added getters and setters to your Foo and Bar classes.

Now just register the Deserializer with

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Container.class, new ContainerDeserializer());
om.registerModule(module);
```

and deserialize using

```
om.readValue(test, Container.class);
```